# subversion mysteriously getting disconnected

Tags: apache, svn, active-directory

This is my first post on the forum, so please excuse any of my mistakes.

We have installed Subversion 1.7.2 with Apache 2.2 on a Windows 2008R2 VM server. And for authentication, svn is integrated with Active directory. We are facing a very strange problem. After 2-3 days of accessing svn, it suddenly becomes inaccessible from svn clients. While accessing the repository url it throws a 500 error. The log file doesn't show any error message. Apache seems to be running as well.

We tried to restart the Apache server but it doesn't resolve the issue. Since log file doesn't show any message its tough to debug. Even windows event log doesn't show anything on this error. The only way we have found is by restarting the server box, which is very embarrassing.

We are now absolutely clue less and planning to upgrade the svn to a higher version but we don't know which version will fix the issue.

Comment: I think you should post this question on superuser.com. It's not a programming question. :)

Comment: After migrating to SU - show 1) `/svn` Location part of Apache config 2) **real output** with error-message from CLI svn-client 3) results of accessing not-svn part of Apache by ordinary http-client (browser)